# Defining JSON in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

so I'm trying to make an Alexa skill in node.js - however, I can't seem to figure out how to define a json element. I need to join all the elements, in this case they are titles from a news API. I have them all console.logg'ed and it works, but all I need to do is figure out how to make "title" a variable. How can my make "title" a variable to include all the titles from the JSON file. Here's my code:

```
 var Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
 var request = require('request');

 var APP_ID = "amzn1.ask.skill.36267067-d40c-460c-b07b-cc603b97be1b";
 var url = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=googlenews&sortBy=top&apiKey=6e23e1ddb67e40cb93cf147718f18e36";


 var handlers = {
     'LaunchRequest': function () {
         this.emit('NewsIntent');
     },

     // Get titles from JSON URL & Output it
     'NewsIntent': function () {

       request({
           url: url,
           json: true
       }, function (error, response, body) {

           if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
             console.log(body.articles[0].title);
             console.log(body.articles[1].title);
             console.log(body.articles[2].title);
             console.log(body.articles[3].title);
             console.log(body.articles[4].title);
             console.log(body.articles[5].title);
             console.log(body.articles[6].title);
             console.log(body.articles[7].title);
             console.log(body.articles[8].title);
             console.log(body.articles[9].title);

///// I need help here!!!!! ----> 
       /// need to define title, so I can speech emit it below. 

             this.emit(':tellWithCard', title.join(''));

           }
       });

     }
 };


 exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the `articles` array with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) then they can be joined later on.

```
var titles = body.articles.map(function(article) {
  return article.title;
});
```

*Note: if any of the titles are undefined that will show in the join.*

**UPDATE:** Based on the gist in your comment, you could do something like:

```
var handlers = {
  'LaunchRequest': function() {
    this.emit('NewsIntent');
  },

  // Get titles from JSON URL & Output it
  'NewsIntent': function() {

    request({
      url: url,
      json: true
    }, function(error, response, body) {
      var titles;
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body.articles[0].title);
        console.log(body.articles[1].title);
        console.log(body.articles[2].title);
        console.log(body.articles[3].title);
        console.log(body.articles[4].title);
        console.log(body.articles[5].title);
        console.log(body.articles[6].title);
        console.log(body.articles[7].title);
        console.log(body.articles[8].title);
        console.log(body.articles[9].title);

        titles = body.articles.map(function(article) {
          return article.title;
        });

        this.emit(':tellWithCard', titles.join(''));
      }
    });

  }
};
```

Comment: so, would this work?? Thanks for your help https://gist.github.com/samayshamdasani/f6e2ce356c7ccd13fc0c8e3c919e929c